# Is there a smallest large set?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, natural-numbers

A set $A = \{a_1, a_2 ,..\}$ of positive integers is called large if $\frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{a_2} + \frac{1}{a_3} + ...$ diverges. A small set is any set of the positive integers that is not large

We define $A(n) = \{1,2,..n\} \cap A$ and $a(n) = |A(n)| $ the number of elements in $A$ less or equal to $n$.

We say that $A$ is smaller than $B$ if:  $ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a(n)}{b(n)} = 0$

I wondered if there exist a "smallest" large set, or whether we can always find a smaller subset. I suspect the latter, the idea of an absolutely smallest large set feels unsettling. Therefore, I conjecture the following:

For any large set $A$, there exist a subset $A^{\ast} \subset A $  so that $A^{\ast}$ is large and smaller than $A$.

Comment: Your conjecture (that there is no smallest) is true. Now, what's Erdos about it?

Comment: @IvanNeretin, please, could you write an example of large set smaller than $\Bbb N$?

Comment: Primes will do.

Comment: Do you have a source Ivan?

Comment: @IvanNeretin, is the set $\,A=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n,\ldots\}\subset\Bbb N\,,\,$ where $a_n=\lfloor (n+1)\ln(n+1)\rfloor\,,\,$ a large set smaller than $\,\Bbb N\,?\,$ If it is, could you write a large set smaller than $\,A\,?\,$

Comment: @Angelo Let's put it this way. $\sum\frac1n$ diverges as $O(\log n)$. Can you imagine a function which grows slower than that, yet still is unbounded? Of course you can: $\log\log n$, and that's how slow your $\sum\frac1{a_n}$ diverges. Now can you imagine a function that grows even slower?

Comment: I know what you're getting at, but: https://oeis.org/wiki/Higher-order_prime_numbers, The prime numbers are growing like $a_n$ in Angelo's $A$. So why then don't the higher-order primes converge?

Comment: They **do** converge. The second-order primes grow like $n\log^2n$, which means the sum of their reciprocals is finite. **Upd.** Your link says so, too.

Comment: Sorry, I meant why don't they diverge?

Comment: Why would they? $\int\limits_2^\infty{dx\over x\log^2x}$ converges, after all.

Comment: But it's not clear how to construct such a series to me. The sum of prime reciprocals grows like log(log(n)), but then how can we go from there to log(log(log(n)))?

Comment: Ah if P-n is the n-th prime and q_n is of the order p_n*ln(ln(p_n)), then Q is large growing like ln(ln(ln(n))), right??

Answer (score 2):

First observe that if $A$ is a finite set of positive integers and $B \subseteq A$ contains every $n$th element of $A$ (starting with the smallest) then $\sum_{b \in B} 1/b \ge (1/n) \sum_{a \in A} 1/a$.

Now let $A$ be a set of positive integers such that $\sum_{a \in A} 1/a = \infty$. We can partition $A$ into segments $A_1, A_2, A_3, \dots$ (with $\max A_n < \min A_{n+1}$ for each $n$) such that $\sum_{a \in A_n} 1/a \ge 1$ for each $n$. We may also arrange that $|A_n|$ is a multiple of $n$. Let $B$ contain every element of $A_1$, every other element of $A_2$, every third element of $A_3$, and so on. Then clearly $B$ has asymptotically zero density in $A$ and $$\sum_{b \in B} 1/b \ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n \sum_{a\in A_n} 1/a \ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n = \infty.$$

Comment: So  you basically set the jumps between b_n relative to the growth of A, right?